# Game maker studio accessing iOS app's NSUserDefaults, is it possible?

Tags: ios, communication, game-maker

I have a native app deployed to my iPhone, and would like to make another app (game) by using game maker studio.

On the native app, I have some data like: username, date of birth, etc. And I would like to access those data from the game.

I have been searching around and most people suggest to use web service for the data communication method. Is there any other way to do it? Maybe sharing a database or using NSUserDefaults. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score -1):

the web service is your best bet as Apple has a big thing about privacy and such for the reason being that they dont want the possibility of the app being accessed and the users data being stolen!
So if you want one app to get data from another app as that is what i am understanding from your question, then as i said sharing the data over a web service is your best bet!
I hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: I really do not know why this was down voted... The answer is reasonable as it tells the truth. Apple doesn't allow a lot of things when it comes to app communicating unless it is something they released a kit for. Can you do it between two apps on Android or even Windows phone? Well possibly and probably.